# TimePicker for API 25

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm creating a Alarm based Application with API version 25.
But TimePicker getCurrentMinute, getCurrentHour method are deprecated.

Which method will replace this method?

```
 TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);

    int currentHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    int currentMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

it does not work.

Comment: Is it giving you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Android official docs .. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

it tells you everything

```
public Integer getCurrentMinute ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 23.
Use getMinute()

Returns
the current minute
```

and

```
public Integer getCurrentHour ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 23.
Use getHour()

Returns
the current hour in the range (0-23)
```

Comment: i do not understand.you are ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);
int currentHour = timePicker.getHour();
int currentMinute = timePicker.getMinute();
```